# list_value cannot contain a Value containing another list_value

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a 2d numeric matrix which I want to store to the cloud-datastore,

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client(project='my-random-project')

complete_key = client.key("Task", "2185e0c5")
task = datastore.Entity(key=complete_key, exclude_from_indexes=['data'])

task.update({'data': {'input': [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 'output': [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]}})

client.put(task)
```

so when I run the code above I get the following error

```
InvalidArgument: 400 list_value cannot contain a Value containing another list_value.
```

How can I put this kind of data to `cloud-datastore` ?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: dump to json and store as a string:

```
import json
data_raw = {
    'input': [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    'output': [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
}
task.update({'data': json.dumps(data_raw)})
```

> You'll need to configure data to accept either `stringValue` (will not allow utilization of values in db side filtering/querying).

A better solution would be to store each value as an index in an object:

```
data_raw = {
    'input': {
        1: [1,2,3],
        2: [4,5,6],
        3: [7,8,9]
    },
    'output': {
        1: [2,3,4],
        2: [5,6,7],
        3: [8,9,10]
   }
}
```

> I'm not 100% sure how to map the entity type here, but you do get a compatible though highly nested object.
> If ordering matters here but you cannot anticipate ordering ahead of time (eq to "on insert, set index"), consider using some hash algorithm to store an ordered index. This is probably a specialized use case which will take a ton of time to develop.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? @jayendra-parmar